# Which font can display ⯨ (Left Half Black Star)

Tags: fonts

I am looking for a font that can display the character ⯨ (U+2BE8 "Left Half black Star") from the unicode block Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows (https://unicode-table.com/en/2BE8/).

Is there any way for me to find out which fonts can display that character? I have already tried out my normal favourites for this case of situation, namely Arial Unicode, Segoe UI Symbol and Consolas, but none of them were able to render the character correctly.

Comment: Try: https://symbl.cc/fonts/u/u2800.woff See also: https://superuser.com/questions/154293/good-font-for-unicode-symbols